# Die Verwendung von »von … bis zu« bei Verben

Tags: grammar, verb, preposition

> Er kann alles machen, vom Einkaufen bis zum Fußbodenfegen.
>
> He can do everything from grocery shopping to sweeping the floor.

Ich frage mich, ob man »von … bis zu« bei Verben benutzen kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja, kann man, wenn die Verben substantiviert werden (wie im Beispielsatz). Ansonsten geht es nicht:

> *Er von einkauft bis den Fußboden fegt.

Auch mit richtigen Substantiven ist das ohne weiteres möglich:

> Er hat schon viele Berufe gehabt, vom Bäcker bis (hin) zum Lehrer.
>   Die Veranstaltungen finden an vielen verschiedenen Orten statt, vom Ratssaal bis (hin) zum Klärwerk.

Sehr häufig wird in diesen Verwendungen *bis* zu *bis hin* erweitert.